Interprétation de "oisillant"
Dans l'anthologie La fauconnerie dans les lettres françaises du XIIe au XIVe siècle, j'ai trouvé ce passage :

“Tout bêlement s'en va lez un aunoi / Toit oisillant, si com par
esbanoi. / Tout bêlement s'en va li damoisiaus / Selonc le bois, assez
prinst des oisiaus.”

Le terme oisillant semble désigner un mouvement ou un son, probablement en lien avec les oiseaux. Est-il correct de le traduire par 'frémissant' ou 'chantant' en français moderne, ou existe-t-il une meilleure interprétation de ce terme dans ce contexte poétique ?

Qui pourrait traduire le texte ? Peut-être "En beauté Il va près d'une aulnaie / Oiselant avec joie / En beauté s'en va le jeune oiseau / Selon le bois, prince des oiseaux", mais je ne connais pas du tout  le vieux Français.

@jlliagre - tu as une traduction?

C'est une interprétation plausible même s'il n'y a pas de trace d'un verbe oisiller. Cet oisillant fait penser à papillonant.
Une autre interprétation serait un participe présent du verbe oiseler qui signifiait chasser à l'oiseau (avec un faucon par exemple) mais on s'attendrait plutôt alors à oiselant.
Edit:
C'est bien la deuxième interprétation qui est la bonne.
Le Godefroy mentionne une autre version de ce poème où le verbe gibecer est utilisé à la place du verbe oisiller qui est donc une variante d'oiseler:

